# How do I securely limit users to only list documents that they've created?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to be able to limit users to only list documents they've created.
The user id is stored in the user field
Obviously I can do

```
db.collection('projects').where('user', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

.. but any tech savvy user could just remove the filter and get everything.

I've limited access in rules like

```
match /projects/{project} {
  allow read,update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user;
  allow create;
}
```

But this doesn't work, you can't list at all.

Is there a way of doing this without creating a subcollection of the user's entry in the user collection? I'd really prefer to have them all in one place.
Surely this is an extremely common scenario.

Comment: I would expect your rule to work with the query you're showing.  What *exactly* happens with that query? If the rule rejects the query, you would expect to see an error.  Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you stored the user_id in the field "user" in firestore. You can use

```
   String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
   db.collection("projects").whereEqualTo("user", uid)...
```

After ellipses you can use .get() with onSuccesss or onComplete or add Snapshot listener.

Comment: Right, but that's an artificial limit as they can easily bypass it by doing a manual query without the filter.
I want the filter to be enforced server side if possible. I guess I'll just have to make a cloud function but then I don't get the benefits of live updates

Comment: What do you mean you don't get "benefits of live updates"? You can add Snapshot listener to almost everything

Comment: Facepalm... I found the solution to my problem at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

I actually thought I did it like that and it wasn't working, it is now - obviously did something wrong the first time

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you got it fixed. :)